# How to use our own fonts in web sites, which is compatible with all users?

Tags: php, asp.net, css, fonts

I need to use different hi-style fonts in my webpage. But i had fear that, if the user had no such font, then they will be displayed with default font. How to use different new font that should be compatible with all users?

Answer (score 4):

Consider using a normal font that everybody has for body-text, the bulk of your content. There are quite a few to choose from. For headlines, use a drawing package (e.g., MS Paint, Photoshop) to format headlines as images using your preferred font. If you want to incorporate a fancier font for your body text, you can always resort to something like this in your CSS:

```
font-family: <some-fancy-typeface>, Calibri, "Gill Sans MT", Helvetica, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
```

Remembering that it will try to use your fancier font first, then fall back through the list of more mundane choices until a match is found. Bear in mind that from a usability standpoint, most people prefer a simple font like Helvetica or Times Roman for their body text (consider Google, Yahoo!, Stack Overflow...). Spicing headlines up with bitmapped images is, of course, part of the spice of web-life.

Answer (score 4):

I use [Cufón](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/). It works with all modern browsers, is light and relatively easy to set up.

Answer (score 3):

You could have a look at something like [sIFR](http://www.mikeindustries.com/blog/sifr/) or [TypeKit](http://typekit.com), which will use flash and javascript respectively to fix custom fonts.

There are not a lot of browsers that support `@font-face` properly yet.

Answer (score 1):

Read this one about Dynamic fonts.

[So, You Want Dynamic Fonts, Huh?](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/getting_started/article.php/3479401)

> Dynamic Fonts
>
> Dynamic fonts are font style files that download right along with
>   the page that will use them. Think of
>   them as an image. That's the basic
>   concept.
>
> When you use these fonts, the font file will download into your
>   cache just like an image. Once there,
>   as long as you don't clear your cache
>   completely, the font will be there for
>   all future visits. It is fun to watch
>   the page the first time you use these
>   fonts. The page will come in fully
>   with the text in the default format.
>   Then, once the font, or fonts,
>   download, the entire page reloads and
>   comes to life. It's a great effect.
>
> The use of these fonts is basically a Netscape Navigator 4.0 or
>   better deal. However, you can also
>   view the fonts using MSIE 4.0 and
>   above if you also include, along with
>   the font, an Active X helper
>   application.

Answer (score 1):

You say you "need" to use "hi-style" fonts for your webpage. If that's really true, you'll need to go with Bob Kaufman's answer. The problem with using images for text, though, is it completely breaks indexing, searches, etc. Instead, consider *not* doing it and sticking with a prioritized list of fonts instead.

When you specify the `font-family`, you can give a list, and the first matching font will be used. This allows for graceful degradation -- if a user has your fancy font, fine, but if not the next best option (as defined by you) is used, e.g.:

```
body {
  font-family: "Nifty Cool Font", "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
}
```

More on the [w3schools page for the `font-family` property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_font_font-family.asp).

Comment: Good point on indexing and search engine spiders. Granted you can do alt="original text", but it just doesn't have the same "kick" as an H1 tag does.

Comment: Not a perfect solution, but a compromise is to use an h1 tag to get the SEO kick and use css to move the text out of view and put an image "in place" of the h1.  It is kludgish, requires more maintenance and I would minimize the use of it but another option nonetheless.  A discussion more for doctype.com though.

Answer (score 0):

Some webpages use a Flash movie just for the headline, in which the typeface can be embedded. You could use images (automatically generated). I personally consider that all bit unprofessional, but different people balance usability and standards against design differently.

And if you are re-distributing fonts, make sure you look at the legal implications.

Answer (score 0):

you can sue javascript to achieve this.

[here's a library as an example.](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/)

There might be more libraries out there who can do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS (as posted before) to reference the .TTF files as shown here: http://weston.ruter.net/2008/08/27/efficiently-serving-custom-web-fonts/

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have many IE visitors on your site you can use [CSS 3 web fonts](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/)

Answer (score 0):

Depends what font you want to use ... the easiest solution is to use the `@font-face` method. If you include the microsoft only format(.EOT) it will work in **ANY** browser.

[Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface) has a great collection of free to use commercially, font kits, that include:

- Original **TrueType** or **OpenType** Fonts
  for Firefox 3.5 and Safari
- **EOT** fonts for Internet Explorer
- **SVG** fonts for Opera, iPhone & Chrome
- **WOFF** fonts for Firefox 3.6+
- Demo.html and stylesheet.css so you
  can get going fast

The `@font-face` method doesn't require Javascript *or* Flash, like the previously mentioned sIFR and Cufon techniques, so is more accessible by all.

It's totally SEO friendly and scalable.